# Failing to compile Maven GWT project

Tags: maven-2, gwt

**Note** - I will really appreciate a quick and complete answer to this question. I can't offer a bounty yet because I just published this question a few hours ago, but if someone answers this question fully, I will issue a total bounty of 150 (100 from me + 50) and award it to them.

I have tried to work my way through the [GWT Archtype](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/archetype.html), but failed. Currently, I'm getting an error finding entry point class, when doing "mvn clean package"

```
INFO] auto discovered modules [org.test.TestGwt]
INFO] Compiling module org.test.TestGwt
INFO]    Finding entry point classes
INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.test.MyEntryPoint'
INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
```

I uploaded the source code [to my dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Programming/Maven/gwt_test/gwt_test1.zip), would appreciate your help. This is a very stripped down project, it only contains the bare essentials - please help me figure out a working example.

My goal is to get [mvn gwt:run](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/hosted.html) to work, and to get a deployable war that actually works.

Comment: Does http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/184882;jsessionid=4656390293ED9B699A90C04CECEFA09C help?

Comment: @VonC - I haven't tested it yet. Please see the Note I added to the question - there will be a bounty here.

Comment: ok, but bounty or no bounty, I would have posted an answer if I had one. Note: I cannot access your project for now, dropbox is blocked at work ;)

Comment: @VonC - where do you work? Not fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the property:

```
<source path="org/test"/>
```

refers to the path relative to your `TestGwt.gwt.xml` file itself. Also don't put server side code in your code base because GWT tries to compile it to JavaScript and will fail because it contains classes not available to compile.

I suggest you add 2 folders to you package structure:

```
org.test.client
org.test.server
```

Leave the `TestGwt.gwt.xml` file in the org/test folder.

and change the gwt.xml to:

```
<source path="client"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted - will award the bounty in 23 hours (minimum wait time)